# NoMethodError when trying to fetch to Rails API endpoint from React frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, google-oauth, fetch

This is really leaving me scratching my head. What I'm trying to do should be pretty straight forward but for some reason I just can't get it working.

As the title says I'm trying to fetch some information from a Rails API endpoint I set up to display in a React component.

My fetch looks like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/api/v1/coffee_formulas`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      this.setState({ formulas: body })
    })
  }
```

And the API endpoint looks like:

```
  def index
    formulas = current_user.coffee_formulas
    render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Loaded coffee formulas', coffee_formulas: formulas }, status: :ok
  end
```

The thing that is confusing me is the fact that I can navigate to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/coffee_formulas` and see the exact JSON that I want to get on the React end. My assumption was that I could make a fetch to the same point but I guess I'm missing something.

A couple things to note

- I am able to successfully post to the same API.
- I'm using Google OmniAuth to generate a session and current_user.
- I've tried setting the state of `formulas` a few different way with the same results. (ex: `formulas: body.formulas`, `formulas: body.coffee_formulas`, etc.)
- The exact error I'm seeing in my terminal is:

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'coffee_formulas' for nil:NilClass):`

- The error in my console is a `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Like I said I figured this was a pretty straightforward thing but I guess I'm missing a pretty crucial detail here. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it ended up being a problem with the fetch its self. The controller was in fact doing what I wanted it to but the fetch needed to be formatted like:

```
  componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`/api/v1/coffee_formulas.json`, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      this.setState({
        formulas: body.coffee_formulas,
        user: body.current_user
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'coffee_formulas' for nil:NilClass)` means that you are trying to invoke `coffe_formulas` method on `nil` class. Your current_user helper returns `nil` so you haven't authorized your request.

Comment: I guess I'm just still unclear on what I'm not getting. If I just get all the coffee_formulas in my database by changing `formulas = current_user.coffee_formulas` to `formulas = CoffeeFormula.all` I don't get an error in my terminal but I still come up with nothing when I try to see what the state of `formulas` is. The other thing that's tripping me up is how current_user comes back as `nil` but when I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/coffee_formulas` I see only the information that is relevant to the current_user. Switching accounts updates as it should too.

Comment: add a break point, E.g [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) right after the `index` method signature and see what you are getting for the current_user, when called via react

Comment: @awesome_treehouse you are probably using `devise` gem. Are you sure that you have added following line to your controller? `before_action :authenticate_user!`
Without this callback current_user won't be resolved.

Comment: @Gregy, so I'm actually not using devise. Just `gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'`. In my ApplicationController I have a helper method the defines the current_user which I thought would give me access to the user who is signed in.

Comment: @awesome_treehouse can you update the question with your's `current_user` method?